# Visual Studio Code gets stuck during attaching remote debugging to flask application in docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

i'm currently to switching from *atom* to *visual studio code* - partly because of the debugging feature.

Unluckily i can't get **remote debugging** running in the following setup:

**web/app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import ptvsd

try:
    ptvsd.enable_attach(secret=None, address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000))
    ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
    ptvsd.break_into_debugger()
except:
    pass


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask Dockerized'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  build: ./web
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
   - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
```

**launch.json**

```
    {
        "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "",
        "host": "localhost"
    }
```

**Problem:** When i run docker-compose i get:

```
starting container flaskdocker ...
starting container flaskdocker ... done
attaching to flaskdocker
```

It just gets stuck there and i can not access the flask app on port :5000 (worked perfectly before attaching debugging to it).

Why? :/ Please help!

I'm on macOS with Visual Studio Code 1.15.1.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources such as tutorials is **off topic**, thus I removed that from your question. Please spend some time at the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Comment: If you check the console of Visual Studio code, you will see huge JS error. That is what causes for things not to work. See this thread for some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647124/visual-studio-code-how-to-remote-debug-python-code-in-a-docker-container/45649274#45649274

Comment: Here on an Ubuntu machine, I examined port communication with telnet and netcat. Upon wait_for_attach(), ptvsd nicely sends out a json string and listens. It's just VS Code that remains silent. When using Visual Studio on a Windows PC, it has no problems attaching to the process on the Linux machine. It seems, VS Code's ptvsd support is just broken.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some problems reported regarding remote debugging from Visual Studio Code using ptvsd > 3.0.0.

The issue mentioned most often is that VSC 'just hangs' when trying to connect to your remote debugger.

For now, use ptvsd 3.0.0:
`pip install ptvsd==3.0.0`