# Breakpoints not triggering in VS Code debug mode when attached to a remote process

Tags: debugging, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code

I wrote a small node application using typescript which is running inside a docker container and I am trying to debug that application in my local machine using VS code according to [this](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/debugging-a-nodejs-es6-application-in-a-docker-container-using-visual-studio-code/) link. I am able to attach the debugger but my breakpoints are not triggering.

Please tell me what wrong I am doing here ?

P.S. - I want breakpoint to work with typescript file instead of generated js file as shown in [this](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2017/05/04/Debugging-Typescript-in-Visual-Studio-Code) link

Structure of my app folder :-

```
/project/
    - ts_files/
          -A/
            -app.ts
          -B/
            -app_handler.ts
    - js_files/
          -A/
            -app.js
          -B/
            -app_handler.js
    - node_modules
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

location of my app in local machine - C:/Users/pie/Documents/project/

location of my app in remote machine - /usr/project/

my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "target": "es2016",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "ts_files/",
    "outDir": "js_files/",
    "watch": false

   }
 }
```

my launch.json configuration in VS code 2017:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "192.168.99.100",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": 
        [
            "${workspaceRoot}/project/js_files/**/*.js"
        ],
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/project/ts_files",
        "remoteRoot": "/usr/project/ts_files"
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how do you know that the debugger is attached?

Comment: I run  app.js as node --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858 js_files/A/app.js in docker container which shows debugger attached when I launch the debugger with attach as option in VS code. As a result when I hit the url in browser , it is paused and VS code notifies me of an exception in a node_module but not pauses or notifies on the breakpoint I apply

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint after you attach? It could be a bug

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it doesnt works

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647124/visual-studio-code-how-to-remote-debug-python-code-in-a-docker-container/45649274#45649274